# How can I remove edges from my DiscretePlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

By default, `DiscretePlot` displays "edges" along the sides and, prominently, align the top when `ExtentSize -> Full` is set. For example

```
DiscretePlot[{0.0273981, 0.0161957, 0.0164603, 0.0200524, 0.0235201, 
   0.0291751, 0.0203139, 0.00744914, 0.0206204, 0.0215697, 0.0841179, 
   0.0243641, 0.0200671, 0.0262562, 0.0268045, 0.0398572, 0.030682, 
   0.0279297, 0.0266079, 0.0303529, 0.0301269, 0.030297, 0.0111498, 
   0.0292085, 0.0334679, 0.0300855, 0.0264582, 0.0237181, 0.0287921, 
   0.0267715, 0., 0.0278168, 0.0267868, 0.0206096, 0.0223239, 
   0.0178952, 0.00802177, 0.020115, 0.0227009, 0.0238601}[[x]], {x, 1,
   40}, PlotRange -> Full, ExtentSize -> Full, PlotStyle -> Gray]
```

produces

[image]

How can I eliminate these features so that the bars are colored and shaded evenly throughout.

Comment: For fun: does anyone recognize the plot?

Comment: Try `PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> 
 Lighter@Gray, ExtentSize -> Full, ExtentElementFunction -> "Rectangle"`

Comment: @Öskå: I'm trying to remove all the edges. So no (a) line along the top, and (b) no lines between the bars. Ideally I'd like to have the option to have (b) but not (a).

Comment: Oh, (b) but not (a)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with [`ExtentElementFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ExtentElementFunction.html) and [`PlotStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotStyle.html):

```
DiscretePlot[{0.0273981, 0.0161957, 0.0164603, 0.0200524, 0.0235201, 
   0.0291751, 0.0203139, 0.00744914, 0.0206204, 0.0215697, 0.0841179, 
   0.0243641, 0.0200671, 0.0262562, 0.0268045, 0.0398572, 0.030682, 
   0.0279297, 0.0266079, 0.0303529, 0.0301269, 0.030297, 0.0111498, 
   0.0292085, 0.0334679, 0.0300855, 0.0264582, 0.0237181, 0.0287921, 
   0.0267715, 0., 0.0278168, 0.0267868, 0.0206096, 0.0223239, 
   0.0178952, 0.00802177, 0.020115, 0.0227009, 0.0238601}[[x]], {x, 1,
   40}, PlotRange -> Full, ExtentSize -> Full, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Opacity@0}], LightGray, Opacity@.5}], 
 ExtentElementFunction -> "Rectangle"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Excellent. Where did you learn that?!

Comment: I pressed `F1` on `ExtentSize` and found `ExtentElementFunction`.. :) Since `"ArrowRectangle"` existed I assumed that `"Rectangle"` should too.

Comment: @Öskå No need to assume `ChartElementData["DiscretePlot"]`

Comment: @belisarius Yes.., I saw it after by evaluating what is being said in the [documentation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RlpLI.png). But `"Rectangle"` is not here..

Comment: @Öskå Just evaluate it. The docs show an erroneous result.

Comment: That's what I did after, but before I had to assume since it's not said in the docs.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius stuff like [that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X5bam.png) can be done too

Comment: Where in the docs is "Rectangle" not listed?  I see it in **DiscretePlot > Options > ExtentElementFunction**. ([Here, for example](http://wolfram.com/xid/0tzxz1j2-iuo5q3))

Comment: @BrettChampion [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RlpLI.png) is what I have in the docs on _v8_. Although when I evaluate it I have [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qfFFS.png).

Comment: @Öskå What's your `$Version`?  I don't see the `...Line` entries in my copies of V8.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`PlotStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotStyle.html)to control the styling of the "tops" while [`FillingStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FillingStyle.html)controls the style of the "bar".

```
DiscretePlot[{0.0273981, 0.0161957, 0.0164603, 0.0200524, 0.0235201, 
   0.0291751, 0.0203139, 0.00744914, 0.0206204, 0.0215697, 0.0841179, 
   0.0243641, 0.0200671, 0.0262562, 0.0268045, 0.0398572, 0.030682, 
   0.0279297, 0.0266079, 0.0303529, 0.0301269, 0.030297, 0.0111498, 
   0.0292085, 0.0334679, 0.0300855, 0.0264582, 0.0237181, 0.0287921, 
   0.0267715, 0., 0.0278168, 0.0267868, 0.0206096, 0.0223239, 
   0.0178952, 0.00802177, 0.020115, 0.0227009, 0.0238601}[[x]], {x, 1,
   40}, PlotRange -> Full, ExtentSize -> Full, 
 FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Gray], PlotStyle -> Opacity[0], ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]