# How do I get rid of the marks at the top of bars in DiscretePlot?

Tags: plotting

I for some data I have

```
Show[{
  DiscretePlot[A, {z, 0, 12}, 
   PlotRange -> {All, {0, 0.5}},
   Filling -> Axis,
   PlotStyle -> Black,
   ExtentSize -> 0.9],
  DiscretePlot[B {z, 0, 12}, 
   PlotRange -> {All, {0, 0.5}},
   Filling -> None,
   PlotStyle -> Gray,
   ExtentSize -> 0.9]
  }]
```

with gives figures that look like

[image]

How do I get rid of the black horizontal lines only, leaving everything else as it is.

Comment: Your `A` and `B` are undefined. You need to provide executable code.

Comment: @BobHanlon: I'm just asking for the appropriate option.

Comment: Your second `DiscretePlot` is missing a comma after `B` and you set the filling to `None`. The black lines are the first plot with filling from the black line to the axis, the gray lines are the second plot with no filling.

Comment: @BobHanlon: Yes. How do I get rid of those horizontal lines, without disrupting whatever filling setting I've chosen?

Comment: @BobHanlon: It turns out I've asked this question [before](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48362/37)?